# Load test error rate failure

Tags: visual-studio-2010, load-testing

I am currently doing a load test to simulate concurrency on apache on an internal network. Below is the response time that i am getting based on 10/50/100/200/500/1000 people. My first question is, how do I deduce whether this load is too much or too little. and latter:

[image: Response time]

Attached below is the error rate[image]

a) It seems to me that when the error rate hits 100%, the response time will fluctuate between 30 - 40 ms even for other tests.

b) And when the error rate is higher for apache, the response time seem to be faster.

Could someone shed some light on why will this is so for a) when the error rate hits 100%, why the response time will fluactuate at 30/40ms and b) why will the response time decrease when the error rate increases.

Thanks for taking your time in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with (a).  However, (b) is fairly common in load testing - particularly for apps where the errors happen early in the request service cycle and generating an error message requires much less work than generating a correct response to the request. BUT, I don't see evidence of that in your results. The response time is increasing as the user load increase, as does the error rate.

Have you increased the connection limits in Apache?  It's pretty well know that by default, Apache is not configured to handle a large number of simultaneous connections.  IIRC, Nginx is. At the load levels your results indicate, this could be impacting your results. Also, is your testing tool using persistent connections?

Answer (score 0):

On rule of thumb to tell whether the load is too much is check if there are errors or response time is too long. In your case, you have non-trivial amount of errors at 50 people (VUser), this means something is wrong. You may want to investigate before increasing the people/VUser.

@CMerrill's answer for b) sounds right. When there is error, the processing load on server may be less (in most cases). For a), the fluctuation of response time around 30ms to 40ms sounds normal.  The key issue is to investigate on the errors.